# How do you enable the Service Cloud Console in a developer org?

Tags: service-cloud-console

I've seen a few pages online that talk about enabling the Service Cloud Console. They all seem to mention creating a new App and selecting "Service Cloud Console" but I don't have that as an option when I'm creating a new app in my dev org.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: [Creating A Service Cloud Console App](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/console2_define_app.htm)

Is there something I need to do before I can create an app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First go to your profile and activate "Service cloud User" option. 
Then try again with service cloud console app :)

[image]

Comment: This will be available provided Service Cloud feature licenses are available

Comment: This worked, although to clarify, the My Profile link takes me to my Chatter profile page, and you want to get to your user detail page, that's where the option to enable the user as a Service Cloud User as shown in the image is.

Comment: For any dummies like me - "Console" is a tab you need to enable/add to one of your applications.

Comment: how do we enable for GUEST user license profile? Is it available?

Answer (score 3):

Is this an old developer edition?  The service cloud console hasn't been around for **that** long, so it may be that the template for your dev org didn't include it.  I have a similar org that doesn't have knowledge feature license.  If that is the case, you can either raise a case with support to have the feature enabled or just spin up a new dev org.  I usually choose the latter as its faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, make sure that you make the app (Sample Console) visible to your user profile. By default, no profiles can view the console.

Answer (score -1):

Latest:
Go to your name--> my setting--> personal--service cloud user

Comment: I think writing an appropriate comment why this was downvoted will help user not to do that again.