# AppExchange / Service Cloud

Tags: appexchange, service-cloud-console

Can Support Users install the *Service Cloud console* custom app using AppExchange?

Comment: As far as I know the service cloud console is functionality that needs to be enabled & configured in salesforce directly, and isn't related to the appexchange. It may be an add-on feature though(i dont know).

Answer (score 1):

First thing the user must have "Service Cloud User" checkbox checked. See link [How do you enable the Service Cloud Console in a developer org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/how-do-you-enable-the-service-cloud-console-in-a-developer-org) to enable it.

Also, To install the package from Appexchange user must have permission:

[image]